# How to call a song in didMoveToView(), once, when switching through several view controllers?

Tags: swift, avfoundation

I'm having a similar question to the one this fellow asked a year ago. The difference is that I am unable to fix it.

[How can I continuously play background music while switching to different views using swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27627769/how-can-i-continuously-play-background-music-while-switching-to-different-views?rq=1)

A user answered his question with this: 
"You can start and stop your music from AppDelegate... The best way would be to create a MusicPlayer Class, instantiate it in AppDelegate and call start and stop methods in it...

Do you have enough experience to write something like that?

Or should I help you?"

Perhaps I need to edit app delegate? Below is what my viewDidLoad function looks like. It is where I call the audio, but every time I load the view controller it will load and play the song in addition to the first time it was loaded. How can I play a song that will be loaded in the view controller and play while the app is running, regardless of which view I am in?

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

            let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Theme", ofType: "wav")

            let soundURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path!)

            do {
                try theme = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: soundURL)
                theme.prepareToPlay()
           } catch let err as NSError {
                print(err.debugDescription)
           }
// trying to make the music refrain from playing simultaneously
             if !theme.playing {
                theme.play()
           }

                theme.numberOfLoops = -1
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put all of that audio player code in your app delegate file within the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method.  That will play the audio file only once when the app first starts and forever until told not to.